# Can one Enable Post-Mortem Debugging of Non-Cygwin Application Running in a Cygwin Terminal?

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, cygwin, windbg

We have a system that's a mix of Cygwin and non-Cygwin programs, all of which run under a Cygwin bash session.

One of the non-Cygwin executables is periodically crashing, and I'm trying to enable post-mortem debugging using windbg [as outlined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I wrote a test program that deliberately crashes.  After following the steps in the above page, windbg opens up automatically when the test program crashes -exactly what I'm looking for.  However, if I run the test program from Cygwin's bash, bash prints a "Segmentation fault" error message and windbg does not open.

Is there a way to get windbg to open up upon a non-Cygwin program, that was launched from a Cygwin bash shell, crashing?

P.S.: All of our non-Cygwin programs are C programs compiled with MS Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin may be installing an unhandled exception filter which allows it to handle the crash and thus print "Segmentation fault". This prevents the just-in-time debugger from launching since the exception was indeed handled by Cygwin. I don't know if you can disable that. To get a memory dump you could use procdump to create memory dumps for all **first chance** exceptions. The final first chance exception memory dump would most likely correspond to the one that caused Cygwin to display "Segmentation fault".

Run your program, then from a Windows command prompt run:
`procdump -e1 <PID|Process Name>`

If your program crashes before you have a chance to run procdump, try running procdump first with the `-w` option so that it will wait for your program to start. Then run your program.

**Make sure** to specify the '1' with the 'e', otherwise you won't get first chance exceptions.

You can get procdump from Microsoft at:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx